# creating two related ASTs with sealed case classes in Scala

Tags: scala, abstract-syntax-tree, case-class, lambda-calculus, sealed

Whenever I've had to create an AST in Scala, I've used the abstract sealed trait/ case class pattern.  It's worked really well so far, having compiler checked pattern matching is a big win.

However now I've hit a problem that I cant wrap my head around.  What if I have 2 languages where one is a subset of the other?  As a simple example consider a lambda calculus where every variable is bound, and another related language where the variables could be bound or free.

First language:

```
  abstract sealed class Expression

  case class Variable(val scope: Lambda, val name:String) extends Expression

  case class Lambda(val v: Variable, val inner: Expression) extends Expression

  case class Application(val function: Expression, val input: Expression) extends Expression
```

Second Language:

```
  abstract sealed class Expression

  case class Variable(val name:String) extends Expression

  case class Lambda(val v: Variable, val inner: Expression) extends Expression

  case class Application(val function: Expression, val input: Expression) extends Expression
```

Where the only change is the removal of scope from Variable.

As you can see there is a lot of redundancy.  But because I'm using sealed classes, its hard to think of a good way to extend it.  Another challenge to combining them would be that now every Lambda and Application needs to keep track of the language of its parameters, at the type level.

This example is not so bad because it is very small, but imagine the same problem for strict HTML/weak HTML.

Answer (score 3):

The classical answer to this problem is to have a single general AST and an additional pass for validation. You'll have to live with ASTs that are well-formed syntactically, but won't pass validation (type-checking).

If you want to distinguish at the type level, the type-checking pass could produce a new AST. You might be able to use path-dependent types for that.

As a side-note, your example seems to have a cycle: to create a `Lambda` you need a `Variable`, but to create a `Variable` you need the outer `Lambda`.

Comment: I did notice the cycles, I lost some correctness trying to create a clear simple example.

Answer (score 1):

When deciding how to generalize, it is sometimes helpful to think of an example function that would need to operate on the generalized structure. So, take some operation that you would want to perform on both bound and free trees. Take eta-reduction:

```
def tryEtaReduce(x: Expression): Option[Expression] =
  x match {
    case Lambda(v1, Application(f, v2: Variable)) if v1 == v2 => Some(f)
    case _ => None
  }
```

For the above function, a generalization like the following will work, although it has an obvious ugliness:

```
trait AST {
  sealed trait Expression

  type Scope

  case class Variable(scope: Scope, name: String) extends Expression
  case class Lambda(v: Variable, inner: Expression) extends Expression
  case class Application(function: Expression, input: Expression) extends Expression
}

object BoundAST extends AST {
  type Scope = Lambda
}

object FreeAST extends AST {
  type Scope = Unit
}

trait ASTOps {
  val ast: AST
  import ast._

  def tryEtaReduce(x: Expression): Option[Expression] =
    x match {
      case Lambda(v1, Application(f, v2: Variable)) if v1 == v2 =>
        Some(f)
      case _ =>
        None
    }
}
```